# Как добавить в build.gradle библиотеку без документации с github?

Tags: android, gradle, build, зависимости

Не могу добавить в свой проект вот эту библиотеку: https://github.com/flussonic/flussonic-watcher-sdk-android .

Когда пробую прописать в dependencies вот это:

```
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar','*.aar'], dir: 'libs')

 implementation (name:'watcher-sdk-1.5', ext:'aar')
```

Естественно, файл с github watcher-sdk-1.5.aar лежит в папке libs, но вываливаются такие ошибки:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform artifact 'watcher-sdk-1.5.aar (:watcher-sdk-1.5:)' to match attributes {artifactType=jar}
```

Хотя библиотека nv-websocket-client-2.6.jar из этой же папки успешно добавляется в проект.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Там есть сэмпл, попробуйте по его примеру настроиться: https://github.com/flussonic/flussonic-watcher-sample-android.

Answer (score 0):

У меня срабатывает так:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation(name:'watcher-sdk-1.5', ext:'aar')
```

Comment: Тоже пробовал такой вариант записи, а также каждую из двух перечисленных строк по отдельности. Все время вываливается одна и та же ошибка.